# Можно ли и как совмещать лицензии GPL 2+ и MIT?

Tags: лицензирование, gnu

Я пишу Open Sourse проект под лицензией GNU GPL 2+, используя в проекте инструменты, которые распространяются по лицензии MIT. Это, собственно, сам фреймворк, на котором разрабатывается проект и отдельные модули с программным кодом.

Можно ли и как совмещать эти две лицензии?

В своих проектах я держу папку LICENSE, в которой находятся оригинальный текст лицензии GNU GPL 2+ и ее текст на русском. При первом запуске проекта первым делом я всегда вывожу окошко, что мол, приложение распространяется под такой-то лицензией, с текстом которой можно ознакомиться и "бла-бла-бла"... В библиотеках своего проекта также указано, что они распространяются под лицензией GNU GPL 2+.

Достаточно ли будет указать в том же окне, при первом запуске проекта, что программа написана с использованием таких-то инструментов с лицензией MIT? Или же мне снабжать каждый модуль, который я использую в проекте шапкой текста лицензии MIT?

Хотелось бы уточнить эти моменты.

Comment: «лицензия mit» — некорректный термин, т.к. в mit применялись разные лицензии. как минимум две из них упомянуты на gnu.org: [expat](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#Expat) и [x11](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#X11License).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Что такое MIT лицензия?**

Так называемая "**лицензия MIT**" это обобщённое название двух лицензий [X11](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:X11) и [Expat](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/License:Expat). Их единственное различие состоит в наличие одного абзаца в X11, который запрещает рекламировать X Consortium без его разрешения, а в Expact он соответственно отсутствует.

**Что разрешает данная лицензия?**

В принципе всё, при условии что текст лицензии будет включен во все распространяемые копии или значительные части ПО.

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

**Можно ли совмещать GNU GPL и MIT лицензии?**

Да. MIT является совместимой с GNU GPL. [Cписок совместимых лицензий с GNU.](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.ru.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses)

**Как совмещать?**

Просто гарантировать, чтобы в используемых Вами инструментах и библиотеках под лицензией MIT присутствовал текст самой этой лицензии. Каких-либо дополнительных действий в виде отображения их в окне приветствия Вашего проекта не требуется. Однако, Вы можете упомянуть об используемых библиотеках в файле LICENSE в корневом каталоге проекта.

Например в проекте GIMP-2.8 помимо основного файла COPYING с лицензией GNU GPL v3, присутствует файл LICENSE в котором даётся пояснение, что некоторые библиотеки проекта (а именно libgimp) имеют другую лицензию отличную от GNU GPL v3 (естественно, совместимую с ней):

> - The GIMP application core, and other portions of the official GIMP   distribution not explicitly licensed otherwise, are licensed under
>     the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE -- see the 'COPYING' file in this
>     directory for details.
> - ...
> - 'libgimp' and the other GIMP libraries are licensed under the
>     GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE -- see the 'COPYING' file in the
>     libgimp directory for details.

**Отказ от отвественности**

Данный ответ написан не юристом и служит лишь для ознакомительных целей. Для более развёрнутой консультации предпочтительнее обратиться к специалисту.

P.S. В качестве бесплатной альтернативы можно изучить исходники других известных проектов под GNU GPL v2+, в которых используются библиотеки под MIT лицензий и посмотреть каким образом они подошли к данному вопросу.